# Does Google Maps have a source country list that I can rely on?

Tags: google-maps

My web application (a photo community) takes GPS coordinates from an image file, and then uses the Google Maps API to reverse geocode these coordinates into an address. The address reliably includes a country name.

In my application, I'm going to link additional elements to the country entity, therefore I'm looking for the total list of countries that Google uses within Google maps.

I'm unable to find this source data. There are lists used by adwords and by translation services, but none found yet for Google Maps itself.

Does anybody know where to find the source country lists used by Google Maps? Or alternatively, which (ISO) standard is being used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the reverse geocoding api docs they mention the use of ISO 3166-1 country codes https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Types

See the sample responses, I'm pretty sure its the same source of data used in the maps api.

Comment: Thank you so much, ISO 3166-1 looks like a safe bet!